# C# fill listbox with combobox selected hard drive's contents

Tags: c#, file, binding, combobox, listbox

I've been wandering how to do this for weeks now, I have a combobox which lists available local hard drives, I can get that far but below that is a listbox, I want the list box to be filled with contents from the selected hard drive dependent on which hdd was selected in the combo box), I not looking for the entire code to be wrote out for me but would like if someone can steer me in a starting direction, much appreciated.

Comment: steering towards System.IO. DirectoryInfo and such

Answer (score 1):

This will get you going in the right direction as for the objects involved to do what you want to do:

```
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
PopulateListBox(listbox1, @"C:\Files", "*.pdf");
PopulateListBox(listbox2, @"C:\Files", "*.doc");
```